# How to get path of the php binary on server where it is located

Tags: php, binary, installation, production-environment, installation-path

I am using the `exec` command as below in PHP :

```
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/Notification.php >> /path/to/log_file.log 2>&1 &");
```

In my local environment (MAMP), I know the PHP installation path, so I can replace `/usr/bin/php` with `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php`. But I don't know where the PHP installation (PHP binary) is located on the production server.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's usually `/usr/bin/php` but you could try to capture and parse the output of the command '`whereis php`' or '`which php'`'.

Or better yet, use the constant `PHP_BINARY` if it is available. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

Comment: I want to find it on server(Production),not on local machine.

Comment: Yes, so have your script run `whereis php` on the server, then parse the output with a regex to get the path.

Comment: Can you explain,What is regex ?

Comment: Thanks dude.Can you tell me by default where it is located on the server?Because I don't have authority to check this command on server.

Comment: @Ponting It's not a command, just use the constant `PHP_BINARY` in your PHP script.

Comment: If you can't find it then you probably have PHP<5.4 . Maybe try using `PHP_BINDIR . "/php"`.

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time, the `PHP_BINARY` [predefined constant](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) should do the job.

If you need something more developed, you can make use of Symfony's [Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), by using its [PhpExecutableFinder](https://github.com/symfony/process/blob/master/PhpExecutableFinder.php) class:

```
// composer require symfony/process

use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;

(new PhpExecutableFinder)->find();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two steps:
updatedb (only needs to be run once to update the locate index)
locate php | grep -P "/php$"

The locate command should show you all files on the server with "php" in their filename or folder name. The "grep" pipe filters down the results down to just things that end in "/php".